# Verify if string matches regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying this code, but I don't know why it isn't working:

```
<script> 
    var inputtxt = '515';
    var letters = /^[0-9]+$/;  


    if(inputtxt.value.match(letters)) {
        document.write('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another');  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        document.write('Please input alphanumeric characters only');  
        return false;  
    }  
</script>
```

I want to input a value (**inputtxt**) and then find if it contains only digits.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean it isn't working?

Comment: dont display any thing...

Comment: It's more semantic to use *test* rather than *match*: `if (letters.test(inputtxt))`. And you're testing only for digits, so naming the regular expression *letters* is a bit misleading. ;-)

Comment: And saying "input **alphanumeric** characters only" is also quite misleading. :-)

Comment: @RobG I don't see how it's any less semantic, and it reads more naturally: if this matches that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the existing answers are getting down voted, but they are correct. If you were to use `console.log(inputtxt.value)` it would print `undefined`.  You need to simply remove that from your if-else:

```
if(inputtxt.match(letters))
    {
        document.write('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another');
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('Please input alphanumeric characters only');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove .value to inputtxt and return true & false from javascirpt

```
<script>

    var inputtxt = '515';
    var letters = /^[0-9]+$/;


    if(inputtxt.match(letters))
    {
        document.write('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another');
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('Please input alphanumeric characters only');
    }
</script>
```